# Options to translate "La vie qu'on nous vend bien tracée"

Tags: sens, traduction, paroles-de-chanson

The phrase "La vie qu'on nous vend bien tracée" in the song "Grandiose" by Pomme is usually understood as "The life that they sold to us" with negative connotation. What if we understand "on" as "we" in the phrase? What would be the meaning of the phrase? Can we interpret it as "we bought (from ourselves) a life with a clear provenance?" = "we designed our life as we wanted it to be" = "we are the source of how our life is"?

corrected

Comment: *on* could be translated *they* or *one*.

Comment: on va danser? on = we here

Comment: As it is written, this question seems to be asking for a translation into English. It should be rephrased to make it clear it is asking for the meaning of *on* the sentence *La vie qu'on nous vend bien tracée*.

Comment: *On* is often expressed by a passive in English. And it is the option I would choose here, the important thing here is to express it is neither you nor me, it's the other people, but "they" really sounds awkward here, and "we are sold" sounds a lot better.

Comment: I wonder where you searched for a translation, chiefly using "usually". I was curious to check for myself and the first two links my search engine led me to had *la vie qu'on nous vend* translated as  "the life (that) we are sold" ...

Comment: "they sold this life to us", "the life that we are sold" -- the meaning is the same: someone sold this life to us. I propose to consider other option: "We sold to ourselves the well-defined life, the live with a clear provenance = the life that we understand and wanted as the opposite to "society inflicted this life on us"

Comment: @None "It should be rephrased to make it clear it is asking" -- corrected, thanks.

Comment: In the context of the song it is definitely closer to "society inflicted this life on us" (although not exactly the meaning). "the meaning is the same:" overall meaning but using the passive focuses differently on the subject. *On* is neutral and very common in French. To keep the same language level in English, in the context of your example, then the passive is better. Using "we" would be a misinterpretation and using "they", in the context of this song lyrics, would make the listener wander who the singer is talking about. If Pomme had wanted to use "ils", then she would have used it.

Comment: @None thanks a lot. The problem is exactly with the the context of this song lyrics. It goes "La vie que j'avais inventée pour toi, la vie qu'on nous vend bien tracée". The structure suggests that the second "la vie" refers to the first "la vie". So it is not clear how it can be that she invented such life and at the same time she buys such live.

Comment: If the meaning had been "the life we sold ourselves", the French would be "La vie qu'on se vend" and not "La vie qu'on nous vend." So because it's not reflexive, *on* and *nous* must be different groups of people.

Comment: @PeterShor very convincing. But what about the contradiction with "inventée" mentioned above? How to interpret the full sentence cohesively?: " la vie que j'avais inventé pour toi, la vie qu'on nous vend bien tracée, une vie comme ça n'existe pas"

Comment: I don't think it's that much of a contradiction — "The life that I had imagined for you, the well-arranged life they sell us, a life like that doesn't exist." Further, these lyrics contain other contradictions: *Le gris de l'église de fond rose*, so the fact that it's a contradiction doesn't mean that the interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: Not the focus of the question, but just to reinforce Peter's translation in the last one of a "well-arranged life" — for "tracé" I picture someone making blueprints for a life with ruler and compass, or a drawing you can't colour outside the lines of, for instance.

Comment: I love this song as well and my reading of the contradiction between "qu'on nous vend" and "que j'ai inventée" is that we're misled into thinking we want a certain life. We're told all these happily-ever-after stories of a particular way that life should turn out, and we imagine this is what we want (what we've come up with ourselves). But as we grow up we realize this isn't even our dream; it was just a template someone sold us and we swallowed it hook, line, and sinker. Not only that, that life doesn't even exist (cf. end of the chorus) — it's just marketing.

Comment: She does **not** buy such a life, she is **sold** such  life. *On* (i.e. society, the media, etc. is what is implied, as far as I understand the song anyway) *nous vend...*.  These words mean: "the life that I had invented for you, the well planned life we are sold, a life like that doesn't exist."  There's no contradiction, society makes us believe in a life that is all mapped out, but such a life doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, thanks to all: I can agree that it is possible that the life that she "invented" is the life "society/the media/etc sells us". Although I'm not sure it was the intention of Pomme :) I would accept the first comment by Peter Shor as "the answer" on the original question.

Comment: @user33924 _La vie inventée_ is not sold by society, the author of the song "invented"/imagined it for her. The second _la vie qu'on nous vend..._ is the one that society wants you to believe is tidy and that the author will have. I think the author _invents_ a life for her that mirrors the tidy one that society is trying to sell. No contradiction.

Comment: @Frank I agree, thank you.

Comment: @PeterShor "La vie qu'on se vend" -- I started to think that this can be an incorrect phrasing. In my understanding, "se" refers to "on" in this structure not to "la vie". Thus, "on se vend" means "they/we/people" are both the subject and the object of "sell".  So I'm not sure now that your reasoning is correct. It seems that "la vie qu'on nous vend" still can be understood as "we sell ourselves the live" technically. What do you think? (however, in a broader context of the discussion, I agree that "they" is more appropriate interpretation)

Comment: @user33924 No, it's clear cut: _la vie qu'on nous vend_: someone else is doing the "selling". _La vie qu'on se vend_: you are selling yourself the life. There is no overlap or ambiguity between the 2 sentences.

Comment: @user33924: In French, *inventée* can mean *invented*, but it can also mean something a little more like *imagined*. So if you translate it: "The life that I had imagined for you, the well-arranged life they sell us, a life like that doesn't exist," there's not a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase

> La vie qu'on nous vend bien tracée,

cannot be interpreted in French as

> the well-arranged life that we sold ourselves.

For it to mean that, you would have to use a reflexive verb:

> La vie qu'on se vend bien tracée,
> La vie que nous nous vendons bien tracée.

So here, *on* and *nous* have to refer to different things. So
what it means (as the other answers say) is something more like:

> The well-arranged life that we were sold,
> The well-arranged life that they sold us.

Comment: I agree - there is no "to ourselves". Someone else is doing the "selling" here.

Comment: @Frank is your opinion based on a broader context of the song or it is impossible for native speakers to understand "on  as "we" in this phrase technically without any context? That's the question I'm interested in. Peter Shor reasons (and I like this approach but I'm doubtful) that "we" would require different phrase structure. Do you agree?

Comment: @user33924: In French, if you do something to yourself, grammar says that you generally need to use the reflexive. You can't say *on nous* where *on* and *nous* both mean *we*.

Comment: @user33924 I'm a native speaker. I agree with Peter Short too.

Answer (score 3):

For non-French people, "on" is pretty hard to get.

## Conjugation

From a conjugation point of view, it is the closest to "it" (third singular person), but carries a different meaning.

## Multiple ways to translate "on"

One meaning can be "we" as you refer. Your translation then starts with "we we" or something along those lines. But I don't think it is the case here since "we" is literally translated by "nous" in French, unless "on" refers to a group of people. Since I don't know the song and its lyrics, I can only do hypothesis.

Example:

- "On m'a dit cela" is translated by "We have been told this/that" or "Some people told me this/that" in English

"On" can also refer to some people/community (back to the previous example) or a common opinion (or some saying/rumor) not necessary true.

Examples featuring the second idea:

- "On dit que cet endroit est hanté" can be translated by "People say that this place is haunted"
- "On dit que les chats on plusieurs vies" can be translated by "We say cats have mutliple lives"

## To conclude

All in all, the closest translation of your sentence with "on" as "we" should be along the lines of:

- "the life we have been promised"
- "the life we are destined to live".

## Answering the remaining questions

1. Can we interpret it as "we bought (from ourselves) a life with a clear provenance?

The verb "vendre" should not be understood as "sell", unless you can sell ideas (English-native people can correct me). "Depicted" or "described" would be more accurate. The provenance is not clear since there are another interference (someone else is describing it) and also you did not earn it.

2. "we designed our life as we wanted it to be"

I think up to this point you got the idea. If you need further explanations, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I cannot get your point on "vendre should no be understood as sell". This is exactly the translations suggested by dictionaries: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/vendre

Comment: @user33924: I believe mie is saying that *vendre* shouldn't be understood as "paying money to obtain something." But in English, *sell* can have a similar figurative meaning, so I think *sell* is a reasonable translation.

Comment: Yes you are right, but a word can have different meanings depending on the context deviating from its original meaning. When you "raise/lift one's spirit", you are not literally lifting/raising anything. But according to @PeterShor the translation is fine here.

Comment: Yes, this is all clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To answer "Options to translate...", I think *bien tracée* shouldn't be overlooked, and the *on* can be translate by a passive form:

> the *tidy/neat* life that we were sold

Or even closer to the original, but a bit iffy:

> the life that we were sold as tidy

The *on* refers to parents, society, friends,... anybody who made the author believe that their life would have a clear or set trajectory. The author is saying that his life, or maybe life in general, is not as neat or tidy as people around you want you to believe.